# Syntax for generating a string literal in order to pass to javascript function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am unable to "encode" a string as a string literal, using `ASP.NET Core Razor Syntax`.

When I debug the generated Html, I get an error message
stating:

> invalid character '@'

The Razor Code I have is this:

```
<script>
//...
control.option("value", @Html.Raw(@Model.Email.ToString()));
//...
</script>
```

The generated Html Line with the error:

```
control.option("value", user@google.com);
```

I see the mistake, the email address is not encoded as a string literal, and I presume also not html safe.

I would suspect the ideal would be:

```
control.option("value", "user@google.com");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have two problems in your code:

1. You are quoting "value", but you aren't quoting the e-mail address.
2. You aren't escaping the e-mail address, so if somehow that variable contained `"`, even if you quoted the resultant string, you would have a problem.

To fix 2, you can escape the string using `System.Web`'s `HttpUtility`:

```
string escapedStringValue = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(stringValue);
```

Now let's combine that to fix 1:

```
control.option("value", "@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(@Model.Email.ToString()))");
```

---

Note that if you use it a lot, you could also make it into an extension method:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering
{
    public static class HelperExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlContent JsString<TModel>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string value)
        {
            return helper.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value));
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
control.option("value", "@Html.JsString(@Model.Email.ToString())");
```